# express and moralis token price API not fetching json data in console

Tags: api, express, web3js, moralis

I've been following  [video link](https://youtu.be/t8U7GRrlYW8?t=2514)  from Moralis web3 (youtube) meanwgile I got stuck when I need to fetch data using token price Moralis API. I want the price details to be printed in the console when i do

```
npm start
```

the expected output in console is:

```
{
  nativePrice: {
    value: '13851123944545175839',
    decimals: 18,
    name: 'Ether',
    symbol: 'ETH'
  },
  usdPrice: 23176.58785953117,
  exchangeAddress: '0x1f98431c8ad98523631ae4a59f267346ea31f984',
  exchangeName: 'Uniswap v3'
}
```

In localhost it should return empty json object '{}' but when I opened the same in localhost it is showing:

```
Cannot GET /tokenPrice
```

I tried different method provided in moralis doc its working fine but I did same as the tutorial that throws me error:

```
const express = require("express");
const Moralis = require("moralis").default;
const { EvmChain } = require("@moralisweb3/common-evm-utils");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();
const port = 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("./tokenPrice", async (req, res) => {
  const { query } = req;

  const responseOne = await Moralis.EvmApi.token.getTokenPrice({
    address: query.addressOne,
  });

  const responseTwo = await Moralis.EvmApi.token.getTokenPrice({
    address: query.addressTwo,
  });

  console.log(responseOne.raw);
  console.log(responseTwo.raw);

  return res.status(200).json({});
});

Moralis.start({
  apiKey: process.env.MORALIS_KEY,
}).then(() => {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening for API Calls`);
  });
});
```

also I want to know what does that {query} & addressOne means here as I've never declared any var like before in my code.

- I want to know what {query} and addressOne is , whether express js property or moralis
- want to know why and where error occured and solution to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `addressOne` and `addressTwo`, those are the query parameters used in your request. If you check the video you can see him showcasing an example of how the request should look like:

```
http://localhost:3001/tokenPrice?addressOne=0x51491...cf986ca&addressTwo=0xdac17f...6994597
```

And use 2 addresses of the tokens you wish to get the price for. You can indeed extend the logic to use more addresses

In the video at minute 45:00 You can see how the code should look like. Please make sure you complete your code for it to work properly.

[image]